# How do I move more than one row when multiple cells match my selection? (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning.  I have an improvement I would like to make to an existing product I have, but am not sure how to get it working.  In my product, an end-user can double-click anywhere on a row, and a before-doubleclick event makes a userform appear asking which other sheet they'd like to move that row to.  It transfers the data over, removes it from the original sheet, and we're all good.  This works fine.  What I'd like it to do is to look at the values in column "A" and Column "I" of the selected row, and move any other rows where those values match as well - this would save my users a ton of time not having to do it one row at a time, as there can be dozens of matches at times. The code I have for moving the single row is as such:

```
`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LastRowTarget As Long
Dim DestSheet As String
Dim ListChoice As String
Dim BLPL As String
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then ListChoice = "White"
If OptionButton2.Value = True Then ListChoice = "Black"
If ListChoice = "White" Then
    If OptionButton3.Value = True Then DestSheet = OptionButton3.Caption & " Whitelist"
    If OptionButton4.Value = True Then DestSheet = OptionButton4.Caption & " Whitelist"
    If OptionButton5.Value = True Then DestSheet = OptionButton5.Caption & " Whitelist"
    If OptionButton6.Value = True Then DestSheet = OptionButton6.Caption & " Whitelist"
Else
    If OptionButton3.Value = True Then BLPL = OptionButton3.Caption
    If OptionButton4.Value = True Then BLPL = OptionButton4.Caption
    If OptionButton5.Value = True Then BLPL = OptionButton5.Caption
    If OptionButton6.Value = True Then BLPL = OptionButton6.Caption
    If OptionButton7.Value = True Then BLPL = OptionButton7.Caption
End If

If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=********
    Sheets(DestSheet).Unprotect Password:=********
    LastRowTarget = Sheets(DestSheet).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Selection.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(DestSheet).Range("A" & LastRowTarget + 1)
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Sheets(DestSheet).Protect (********), DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
Else
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=********
    Sheets("Blacklist").Unprotect Password:=********
    LastRowTarget = Sheets("Blacklist").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Selection.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Blacklist").Range("A" & LastRowTarget + 1)
    Sheets("Blacklist").Cells(LastRowTarget + 1, 20).Value = BLPL
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Sheets("blacklist").Protect (********), DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
End If

Unload Me

End Sub`
```

I would love to attach the workbook itself for you to see what I'm talking about, but unfortunately it's full of classified data.  Apologies, and thanks for your time - this website has been an absolute gold mine for me to brute-force my way into learning this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the following

```
Selection.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(DestSheet).Range("A" & LastRowTarget + 1)
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

with a loop

```
'Remember the values to compare
dim columnAValue
dim columnIValue
columnAValue=selection.entirerow.cells(1,"A").Value
columnIValue=selection.entirerow.cells(1,"I").Value
dim currentRow as long
'dont know where your list starts
'Start from the end so currentRow stays correct if someting is deleted
for currentRow = Activesheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row to ? Step -1
    'Do you mean both have to be the same or only one? If only one replace "and" with "or"
    If Activesheet.Cells(currentRow,"A").Value = columnAValue and Activesheet.Cells(currentRow,"I").Value = columnIValue  then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(currentRow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(DestSheet).Range("A" & LastRowTarget + 1)
        ActiveSheet.Rows(currentRow).Delete
        'Update last row target
        LastRowTarget =LastRowTarget +1
    end if
next
```

do something similar with

```
Selection.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Blacklist").Range("A" & LastRowTarget + 1)
Sheets("Blacklist").Cells(LastRowTarget + 1, 20).Value = BLPL
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Perfect!  It seems so simple looking at it now.  I'd had a work-around by concatenation, but this is a much easier solution.  Thanks a million.